# React: loading and updating nested resources when URI changes without excess duplication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux, react-router

Let's say I have a nested URI structure, something like the following:

> http://example.com/collections/{id}
>
> http://example.com/collections/{collectionId}/categories/{id}
>
> http://example.com/collections/{collectionId}/categories/{categoryId}/book/{id}

I can use `react-router` to render the correct component on page load, and when the URI changes.

Let's take the first case:

> http://example.com/collections/{id}

Let's assume we have a `CollectionShow` component.

When the component first loads, I can pull the collection ID out of the URI and load the correct collection:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.id);
}
```

(Assume that `loadCollection` loads a collection with an AJAX call and sets it into the component's state.)

However, when the URI changes (through, e.g., the user clicking on a `<Link>`, `react-router` doesn't entirely re-build the component, it simply updates its props, forcing it to rerender. So, in order to update the compomnent's state, we also need to update the state on update:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!this.state.collection || this.collectionDidChange(prevProps)) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
}

collectionDidChange(prevProps) {
  return String(prevProps.match.params.id) !== String(this.props.match.params.id)
}
```

So far so good. But what about the second URL?

> http://example.com/collections/{collectionId}/categories/{id}

Let's assume we have a `CategoryShow` component.

Now we don't only have to consider the `collectionId` changing, but also the category ID. We have to reload the collection if that ID changes, and we also have to reload the category if *that* changes.

The problem compounds with a third-level nesting (a `BookShow` component). We end up with something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!this.state.collection || this.collectionDidChange(prevProps)) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.collectionId);
  }

  if (!this.state.category || this.collectionDidChange(prevProps) || this.categoryDidChange(prevProps)) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.collectionId)
        .then(() => this.loadCategory(this.props.match.params.categoryId);
  }

  if (!this.state.book || this.collectionDidChange(prevProps) || this.categoryDidChange(prevProps) || this.bookDidChange(prevProps)) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.collectionId)
        .then(() => this.loadCategory(this.props.match.params.categoryId)
        .then(() => this.loadBook(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
}
```

Not only is this unwieldy, it also results in a fair amount of code duplication across the three components, `CollectionShow`, `CategoryShow` and `BookShow`.

Using redux won't help matters much, because we still have to update the global state when the URI changes.

Is there a clean, efficient, React-friendly way of handling updates of nested resources such as these?

Comment: Maybe you can split up the component and handle the `Category` and `Book` fetching in their own components.

Comment: Trouble is, `BookShow` needs access to the current collection and current category. It's precisely this nested nature of the resource that's causing me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `CollectionPage` component that handles all the AJAX calls and keeps data in state. 
This could pass down the `collection`, `category`/`categories` and `books` to the components (`CollectionShow`, `CategoryShow` and `BookShow`).

In `CollectionPage` you could use `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` as you presented it.

Your `<*>Show` components will know nothing about `props.match.params.*` and will only get the data needed to render the wanted content.

`CollectionPage` can be use for all your routes or you could change the route to something like

```
/collections/:collectionId?/:categoryId?/:bookId?
```

making all params options. You can check for the available ids in `CollectionPage`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I started a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pozvqz157?module=%2Fcomponents%2Fapp.js) but I'm not sure what your `*Show` components display and how your data is shaped.
You can extend this sandbox to test this approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem it is something architectural. The parent component is the one that should be doing this management and injecting the result through subcomponents. Split your component in small components and render each one accordingly.

- The code you shared will be splint in 3 others
- The mponentDidUpdate(prevProps) method will go to the parent component simply as  a componentDidMount().
- Then if the router changes the component will be recreated and the new values will be sent across the modules.
- If you dont wanna split you code you should at least do the step 2.

```js
//everytime you get to the router this will be triggered and depending of the parameters of your router, you get the values you need and set the state
componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.state.collection) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.collectionId);
  }

  if (!this.state.category) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.collectionId)
        .then(() => this.loadCategory(this.props.match.params.categoryId);
  }

  if (!this.state.book) {
    this.loadCollection(this.props.match.params.collectionId)
        .then(() => this.loadCategory(this.props.match.params.categoryId)
        .then(() => this.loadBook(this.props.match.params.id);
  }
}


render() {
  return (
    //you can add conditions to render as well
    <CollectionComponent {...this.props} {...{
        collection: this.collection
    }} />
    <CategoryComponent {...this.props} {...{
        categ: this.categ
    }} />
    <BookComponent {...this.props} {...{
        book: this.book
    }} />
  )
}
```